# Vaadin. Navigation among html-based resources

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

i added a couple of html files to my Vaadin project layout. These files are "interconnected" with each other via anchors. In browser i can navigate to them w/o any problems, but in Vaadin app after click on link i see the following:

> The view could not be found You tried to navigate to a view ('')
>   that does not exist.

After that my address bar in browser contains the follwing address:

> http://127.0.0.1:8090/page3.html

How should i handle the navigation in Vaadin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you use the Navigator to navigate to your html pages. With the Navigator you can only navigate to Vaadin Views, that are registered using `addView(..)`, not arbitrary html pages. To do that use `Page.getCurrent().setLocation(<your url>)`.